# surface integral of over a spherical surface

Tags: integration

I need to prove that
$$\int_{s:x^Tx=c^2}g(a^Tx)ds=\frac{2c\pi^{(n-1)/2}}{\Gamma((n-1)/2)}\int_{-c}^{c}g(||a||x)(c^2-y^2)^{(n-3)/2},$$

where $x,a\in \Re^n.$ I have no experience in dealing with surface integrals, please suggest some way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Using a rotation and a scaling you can reduce yourself to the case of $a=(0,0,\ldots,0,1)$. The rotation is done as follows. If $R$ is the rotation matrix such that $Ra=(0,\ldots,0,1)$, the change of variable $x=Ry$ is the one to perform in the integral on the left hand side.

Using cylindrical coordinates on $\mathbb R^n$ you can show that the surface element $ds^{n-1}$ on the $n-1$ sphere satisfies: $$ds^{n-1}=(1-x_n^2)^\frac{n-3}{2}dx_n ds^{n-2}.$$ So 
$$
\int_{x^Tx=1} g(x_n)\, ds^{n-1}= |\mathbb S^{n-2}|\int_{-1}^1 g(x_n)(1-x_n^2)^\frac{n-3}{2}\, dx_n.$$

Comment: I don't understand the rotation part.

Comment: @AbhinavGupta: I added some details.

Comment: Thank you! It is helpful.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad it helped